# Widget tweaks error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks' with Django forms

Tags: django, django-widget-tweaks

I am trying to customize my Django forms using widget tweaks for an app I'm building with a group and I keep getting an error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'`

I don't understand why.

I installed the module on my mac with `$ pip install django-widget-tweaks` and placed `'widget_tweaks'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS = [...]` part of my app's `settings.py` file. Those were the only 2 things I saw that I needed to do after reading the documentation for how to use widget tweaks.

`settings.py` file snippet:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'PupsToPet.apps.PupstopetConfig',
    'widget_tweaks',
   #'django.contrib.easy_maps',
]
```

Comment: Did you add this tag at top of your template {% load widget_tweaks %}

Comment: Hi Balaraju, yes I did but my code still throws the error.

Answer (score 29):

Try to install with `pip3`:

```
pip3 install django-widget-tweaks
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem and it was killing me!

(for me) The problem was that I was working in an virtural env in PyCharm) but I have a global python as well. From my command line I was running manage.py runserver, the problem being that my global python doesn't have the widget-tweaks library installed. ( I didn't realize I wasn't running from the venv)

If you're like me the solution is make sure you're in the right environment,

from PyCharm I did tools -> run manage.py task -> runserver

and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

I got this since I added `'widget_tweaks',` above the started apps.
You need to add it under the started apps, you can add pip installed like this `INSTALLED_APPS += [ 'widget_tweaks', ]` under `INSTALLED_APPS`.
Only add pip installed apps in `INSTALLED_APPS += []` and started apps in `INSTALLED_APPS = []`.

Or you can just add the pip installed apps bellow the started apps. Like this:

***Settings.py*** only showing **INSTALLED_APPS**

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'PupsToPet.apps.PupstopetConfig',
    ...
     
    # Started apps first
    'app1',
    'app2',
    ...

    # pip installed at the bottom
    'widget_tweaks',
    ...
    
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh this is working for me look when write 
python -m pip install Pillow
this problem solved for me

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved after upgrading my pip version from 21.0.1 to 21.1.1 using `pip install --upgrade pip`